# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'controllery'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want create Rest Web Services And it worked . I changed the code and 
 now i have this error :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'controllery' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\amir\workspace\gu\target\classes\gu\webservice\controller\Controllery.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'interfaceImpl' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\amir\workspace\gu\target\classes\gu\webservice\impl\InterfaceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class gu.webservice.domain.Test     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1242)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1230)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   gu.webservice.GuApplication.main(GuApplication.java:11) [classes/:na]
>   Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'interfaceImpl' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\amir\workspace\gu\target\classes\gu\webservice\impl\InterfaceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class gu.webservice.domain.Test     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:198)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     ... 19 common
>   frames omitted Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'testRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class gu.webservice.domain.Test     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:819)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:725)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     ... 33 common
>   frames omitted Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a
>   managed type: class gu.webservice.domain.Test     at
>   org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]   at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:180)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:118)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:101)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
>   ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.11.RELEASE.jar:2.0.11.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1753)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1690)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]     ... 44 common
>   frames omitted

Hear is my Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/start")
public class Controllery {
    //private static final org.jboss.logging.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.logger(Controllery.class);
    @Autowired
    Services test;
    public Controllery(Services test) {
        //super();
        this.test = test;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public List<Test> customercontroll(){
        return test.findAllTest();
    }
     @PostMapping("/employees")
        public Test createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Test employee) {
            return test.SaveTest(employee);
        }
```

And my repository interface:

```
@Service
public interface TestRepository extends  JpaRepository<Test ,Long> {

    Test findByLastname();
}
```

my service class:

```
package gu.webservice.impl;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import gu.webservice.domain.Test;
@Service
public interface Services{
    Test findTestById(Long id);
    List<Test>findAllTest();
    Test SaveTest(Test test);
    //Test findTestByLastName();
}
And Service impl:
package gu.webservice.impl;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import gu.webservice.domain.Test;
import gu.webservice.repository.TestRepository;
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc //THIS
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "guru.services")

public  class InterfaceImpl implements Services{
    TestRepository test;
    Test entity;
    public InterfaceImpl(TestRepository test) {
    //  super();
        this.test = test;
    }

    /*@Override
    public Test findTestById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return test.getOne(id);
    }
*/
    @Override
    public List<Test> findAllTest() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<Test>) test.findAll();
    }

    public Test SaveTest(Test test) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.test.save(test);
    }
/*
    @Override
    public Test findTestByLastName() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return test.findByLastname();
    }
*/
    @Override
    public Test findTestById(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Bootstrap class:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import gu.webservice.domain.Test;
import gu.webservice.repository.TestRepository;
public class TestBootstrap implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    TestRepository test;
    public TestBootstrap(TestRepository test){
        this.test=test;
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test t=new Test();
        t.setId(1);
        t.setName("ali");
        t.setLastname("rezaii");
        test.save(t);

    }

}
```

Can any one help me to solve problem?

Comment: Can you provide `Test` class source code?

Comment: In your repository change `@Service` with `@Repository`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED :** In your Repository change `@Service` with `@Repository`

And in your `InterfaceImpl.java` you need to inject your Service with `@Autowired`.

It's must be like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc //THIS
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "guru.services")

public  class InterfaceImpl implements Services{

@Autowired
TestRepository test;
Test entity;

// ADD GETTERS AND SETTERS OF test

public InterfaceImpl() {
super();
}
// ALL METHODS HERE
}
```